# How to pass a message from Flutter to Native?

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

How would you pass info from Flutter back to Android/Native code if needed to interact with a specific API / hardware component?

Are there any Event Channels that can send info the other way or something similar to a callback?

1. The [platform_channel](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/) documentation points out "method calls can also be sent in the reverse direction, with the platform acting as client to methods implemented in Dart. A concrete example of this is the [quick_actions plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/quick_actions)." I don't see how the native side is receiving a message from Flutter in this instance.
2. It looks like a [BasicMessageChannel](https://docs.flutter.io/javadoc/io/flutter/plugin/common/BasicMessageChannel.html)’s send() method can be used to send "the specified message to the platform plugins on this channel". Can anyone provide a simple implementation example of this?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

This is a simple implementation showcasing:

1. Passing a string Value from flutter to Android code
2. Getting back response from Android code to flutter

Code is based on example from: https://flutter.io/platform-channels/#codec

1. Passing string value "text":

   ```dart
   String text = "whatever";

   Future<Null> _getBatteryLevel(text) async {
   String batteryLevel;
   try {
     final String result = await platform.invokeMethod('getBatteryLevel',{"text":text}); 
     batteryLevel = 'Battery level at $result % .';
   } on PlatformException catch (e) {
     batteryLevel = "Failed to get battery level: '${e.message}'.";
   }

   setState(() {
     _batteryLevel = batteryLevel;
   });
   ```
2. Getting back response "batterylevel" after RandomFunction();

   ```dart
   public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {
       if (call.method.equals("getBatteryLevel")) {

           text = call.argument("text");
           String batteryLevel = RandomFunction(text);

           if (batteryLevel != null) {
               result.success(batteryLevel);
           } else {
               result.error("UNAVAILABLE", "Battery level not available.", null);
           }
       } else {
           result.notImplemented();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: how to get a list of string

Comment: @Yeahia2508 do you have the answer?

Comment: I solved my problem using other method. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52456013/how-to-retrive-list-of-string-from-method-channel

Comment: @Yeahia2508 I have find a solution to do it on the good way. If you are still interested, let me know

Comment: Please add your  answer in my so question. @Gregga17

Comment: For more information, you can refer this: https://medium.com/@milindmevada/integrating-third-party-native-sdks-in-flutter-df418829dcf7

Comment: You can find the detailed information on the battery level example here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: how to pass custom object like user or employee from flutter to android ?

Comment: can someone tell  me why it doesnt work on ios?
@UpaJah


String text = "whatever";

Future<Null> _getBatteryLevel(text) async {
String batteryLevel;
try {
  final String result = await platform.invokeMethod('getBatteryLevel',{"text":text}); 
  batteryLevel = 'Battery level at $result % .';
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  batteryLevel = "Failed to get battery level: '${e.message}'.";
}

setState(() {
  _batteryLevel = batteryLevel;
});

Answer (score 8):

**Objective C**

```
call.arguments[@"parameter"]
```

**Android**

```
call.argument("parameter");
```

Comment: What about android?

Comment: Android - Java ---> call.argument("parameter");

Comment: how about in kotlin

Comment: @HZan, in Kotlin: `val s: String? = call.argument("parameter")`

Comment: @HZan What about the CPP window side?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, flutter does has an [`EventChannel`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/EventChannel-class.html) class which is what you are looking for exactly.

[Here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/platform_channel) is an example of that demonstrates how `MethodChannel` and `EventChannel` can be implemented. And
[this](https://medium.com/@svenasse/flutter-event-channels-89623ce6c017) medium article shows how an `EventChannel` can be implemented in flutter.

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 6):

for swift

```
    guard let args = call.arguments as? [String : Any] else {return}
    let phoneNumber = args["contactNumber"] as! String
    let originalMessage = args["message"] as! String
```

Answer (score 6):

Passing from Flutter to native:

```
await platform.invokeMethod(
  'runModel', 
  {'path': imagePath!.path} // 'path' is the key here to be passed to Native side
);
```

For Android (Kotlin):

```
val hashMap = call.arguments as HashMap<*,*> //Get the arguments as a HashMap

val path = hashMap["path"] //Get the argument based on the key passed from Flutter
```

For iOS (Swift):

```
guard let args = call.arguments as? [String : Any] else {return}
let text = args["path"] as! String
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to share the data from native to flutter with invoke method
follow this:

main.dart

```
Future<dynamic> handlePlatformChannelMethods() async {
  platform.setMethodCallHandler((methodCall) async {
   if (methodCall.method == "nativeToFlutter") {
     String text = methodCall.arguments;
     List<String> result = text.split(' ');
     String user = result[0];
     String message = result[1];
    }
   }
  }
```

MainActivity.java

```
 nativeToFlutter(text1:String?,text2:String?){
 MethodChannel(flutterEngine!!.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, 
  CHANNEL.invokeMethod("nativeToFlutter",text1+" "+text2);
 }
```

Comment: How could I share the data from flutter to Android native.

Comment: Hi, you can follow this [link](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/#codec)