# How to retrive List of String from method channel

Tags: android, flutter

I want to retrieve List of String from native Android to flutter via Method Channel. This list of string is all contact phone number. My current code:

```
 new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
        new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
          @Override
          public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {
            if (call.method.equals("getContacts")) {
              contacts = getContactList();

              if (contacts != null) {
                result.success(contacts);
              } else {
                result.error("UNAVAILABLE", "not avilable", null);
              }
            } else {
              result.notImplemented();
            }
          }
        });
```

In Flutter:

```
final Iterable result = await platform.invokeMethod('getContacts');
  contactNumber = result.toList();
```

But I'm not getting any response from flutter. How to retrive just phone number from native android to flutter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how i did it.

Android Native code (Send list with Strings):

```
new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
            new MethodCallHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, Result result) {
                    if (call.method.equals("samples.flutter.io/contact")) {
                        final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                        list.add("Phone number 1");
                        list.add("Phone number 2");
                        list.add("Phone number 3");

                        result.success(list);
                    } else {
                        result.notImplemented();
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

Flutter Code:

```
List<dynamic> phoneNumbersList = <dynamic>[];

Future<List<String>> _getList() async {
   phoneNumbersList = await methodChannel.invokeMethod('samples.flutter.io/contact');
   print(phoneNumberList[0]);
   return phoneNumberList;
}
```

Comment: What if I have a custom Class? and I want to retrive as a List?

Comment: @Yeahia2508 If you have a custom class of Contacts, i think the only thing you need to change is List<String> to List<Contacts> on both platforms.

Comment: @Gregga17 how to send list of strings from flutter to native

Comment: @kartheekij I have not try this but you can try, List<String> list; await methodchannel.invokeMethod('channelName', {"sendListToNativeName": list}); and on native side ArrayList<String> value = call.argument("sendListToNativeName");

Comment: @Gregga17 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53903890/how-to-navigate-from-android-to-flutter. android actviity have some ui too

Comment: For custom class changing List<String> to List<Contacts> does not work it throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported value: Contacts.

I found the solution on below link  for custom classes https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/MethodChannel/invokeMethod.html

Comment: @Gregga17 how can i recieve this data to flutter even the app is closed

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException when sending list from native code to flutter using platform.invokeListMethod()

Answer (score 1):

#### Null Safe Code

**Java side (sending data):**

```java
@Override
public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine)
{
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);

    new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), "foo_channel")
            .setMethodCallHandler((methodCall, result) -> {
                if (methodCall.method.equals("methodInJava")) {
                    // Return your List here.
                    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                    list.add("A");
                    list.add("B");
                    list.add("C");
                    result.success(list);
                }
            });
}
```

**Dart side (receiving data):**

```dart
void getList() async {
  var channel = MethodChannel('foo_channel');
  List<String>? list = await channel.invokeListMethod<String>('methodInJava');
  print(list); // [A, B, C]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using another simple method. Maybe it will be helpful for others.

**Native Code:**

```
package com.y34h1a.test;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

  private static final String CHANNEL = "samples.flutter.io/contact";
  String phoneNumbers = "";

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);

      new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
              new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
                  @Override
                  public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {
                      if (call.method.equals("getContacts")) {
                          phoneNumbers = getPhoneNumbers();

                          if (phoneNumbers != null) {
                              result.success(phoneNumbers);
                          } else {
                              result.error("UNAVAILABLE", "Contacts not found", null);
                          }
                      } else {
                          result.notImplemented();
                      }
                  }
              });
  }

  String getPhoneNumbers(){

      Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
      while (phones.moveToNext())
      {
          String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

          if (phoneNumber != null)
            phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers + phoneNumber + ",";

      }
      return phoneNumbers;
  }
}
```

**Flutter Code:**

```
static const platform = const MethodChannel('samples.flutter.io/contact');

final String result = await platform.invokeMethod('getContacts');
List<String> phoneNumbers = result.split(",");
```