# How to retrieve a model from method channel?

Tags: java, android, flutter

I want to retrieve a model from native Android to Flutter via Method Channel. My current code:

```
       new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
                new MethodCallHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMethodCall(MethodCall methodCall, Result result) {
                        if (methodCall.method.equals("getModel")) {
                            
                            NewModel model = new NewModel();
                            model.id = 1;
                            model.title = "Title is here!";

                            result.success(model);
                        }

                    }
                }
        );
```

Here is my `NewModel`:

```
class NewModel {
    public int id;
    public String title;
}
```

In Flutter, I have the same model and tried to get a response with the following code:

```
NewModel response = await platformMethodChannel.invokeMethod('getModel');
```

```
class NewModel {
  int id;
  String title;
}
```

Here is the error:

```
E/MethodChannel#com.methodchannel/test(25656):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/MethodChannel#com.methodchannel/test(25656):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#com.methodchannel/test(25656):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
E/MethodChannel#com.methodchannel/test(25656):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#com.methodchannel/test(25656):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
E/MethodChannel#com.methodchannel/test(25656):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
E/MethodChannel#com.methodchannel/test(25656):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7211)
E/MethodChannel#com.methodchannel/test(25656):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#com.methodchannel/test(25656):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
E/MethodChannel#com.methodchannel/test(25656):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

How can I fix this?

Note: I can successfully get the only `string` response and `string list` response as previously asked in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52456013/how-to-retrive-list-of-string-from-method-channel). But I can not get a model. So, it is not a duplicated question.

Comment: Are you sure you are invoking the method on the right `methodChannel` in Flutter?

Comment: Yes. I can get a string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your model to JSON. Then you can convert JSON to model.

First, you need to add `toString()` method in your `Java` model like this:

```
class NewModel {
    public int id;
    public String title;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return   "{\"id\": "+id+",\"title\": \""+ title+"\"}";
    }
}
```

Then, you can convert your model to `String` like this:

```
   new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
            new MethodCallHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onMethodCall(MethodCall methodCall, Result result) {
                    if (methodCall.method.equals("getModel")) {
                        
                        NewModel model = new NewModel();
                        model.id = 1;
                        model.title = "Title is here!";

                        result.success(model.toString()); // In here!
                    }

                }
            }
    );
```

---

```
  string response = await platformMethodChannel.invokeMethod('getModel');

   NewModel model=json.decode(response);
```