# Communication between android and flutter

Tags: flutter

I am new on flutter. I want to communicate between Android and flutter. I have opened an android activity from flutter using Method channel. Now from the current android activity. I want to open a dart file on the click of a button. How can I achieve this in Flutter?

//This is the main. dart class from which I have opened an activity using method channel.

```
class Communication extends StatefulWidget
{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
  return MyCommunication();
}



}


class MyCommunication extends State<Communication>
{

static const platform = const MethodChannel("test_activity");
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return MaterialApp(

  home: Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      child: getNewActivity(),

    ),
  )

      /*new MaterialButton(
        child: const Text('Open Screen'),
        elevation: 5.0,
        height: 48.0,
        minWidth: 250.0,
        color: Colors.blue,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        onPressed: () {
          _getNewActivity();
        })*/

);
```

}

```
getNewActivity() async{

  try {
  await platform.invokeMethod('startNewActivity');
   } on PlatformException catch (e) {
  print(e.message);
  }

    }

 }
```

//This is my Main Activity

class MainActivity(): FlutterActivity() {

```
private val CHANNEL = "test_activity"
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)



MethodChannel(flutterView, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
        object : MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler {
          override fun onMethodCall(call: MethodCall, result:        MethodChannel.Result) {
            if(call.method.equals("startNewActivity")) {
              startNewActivity()
            }
          }
        })

 }

  private fun startNewActivity() {
  val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
  startActivity(intent)
  }



 }
```

//this is the second activity from which I have to open dart file which has some widgets in it.

```
class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
  override fun onClick(p0: View?) {

    when(p0!!.id)
    {
        R.id.btn ->
        {
            var intent =  Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_RUN)
            intent.putExtra("route","screen2");
            startActivity(intent);


           }
       }

    }

  var button:Button?=null



   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.second_actvity)
    button=findViewById(R.id.btn);
    button!!.setOnClickListener(this)
   // setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    // Now get the support action bar
    val actionBar = supportActionBar

    // Set toolbar title/app title
    actionBar!!.title = "Android Component"
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

}

   override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    onBackPressed()
    return true
     }



   }
```

Comment: https://flutter.io/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#developing-plugin-packages (the same stuff can also be used directly in your application project)

Comment: can you please share me the code regarding this.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/plugins are all packages for only this purpose to make various native features available to Flutter/Dart. https://pub.dartlang.org/flutter/packages?q=plugin lists the same and more from the community.

Comment: as described in docs you got to create channels on your android project. 
Exemples are in docs. This official doc is well done and complete

Comment: I have edited my question. Now in this do I need to create one more method channel for this. Plz help I don't know how to do it programmatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a message from Flutter to Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49099408/how-to-pass-a-message-from-flutter-to-native)

Answer (score 0):

Use method Channel for communicate between Android, IOS and flutter you can check following Url.
https://medium.com/flutter/flutter-platform-channels-ce7f540a104e

```
new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
            new MethodCallHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, Result result) {
                    // Note: this method is invoked on the main thread.
                    // TODO
                }
            });
```