# how to call android activity from dart file in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

can anyone tell me how to call android activity from dart file in flutter.
Thank you.

code:

```
class FlutterScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Android'),
          onPressed: () {
            // Navigate to Android activity screen when tapped!
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking for is the [android_intent library](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/android_intent).

With it, it's easy to trigger an intent. You'll have to make sure that you don't use it the same way on iOS though as iOS isn't supported.

Example code from the android_intent readme:

```
if (platform.isAndroid) {
  AndroidIntent intent = new AndroidIntent(
      action: 'action_view',
      data: 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?'
          'id=com.google.android.apps.myapp',
      arguments: {'authAccount': currentUserEmail},
  );
  await intent.launch();
}
```

Comment: here i want to write some native code on android platform for printing via bluetooth from dart file. so i need move from flutter to native android

Comment: If that's what you were actually asking, then this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49099408/how-to-pass-a-message-from-flutter-to-native.  You could also check the documentation out at https://flutter.io/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: ok. i tried this. 
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel showing error. import are not not taking. extends FlutterActivity also not showing :(

Comment: @kartheekij you should create another question for these issues.