# Reusable components with Flutter

Tags: android, ios, mobile, flutter, cross-platform

**The problem**

My idea is to create some simple components using Flutter so that they can be used in multiple native iOS and Android projects in our firm.

For example, consider a generic login view. This view can be coded once in Flutter and then can be included later on into projects that have both iOS and Android parts(native) . So such common components can be written once using Flutter instead of twice as native iOS and Android components.

**What I have tried so far**

I have followed the steps here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps and it works, but it seems very restricted in functionality.

**My questions are**

1. How can I add multiple flutter projects like this, with each project representing a reusable component? Is that even the way to go?
2. Can I have smaller components- for example in iOS, UIViews instead of FlutterViewController without native hacking ?
3. How do I handle passing data between the native and Flutter part and also the navigation?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "*it seems very restricted in functionality*" ?

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app lists these limitations:

- Running multiple Flutter instances or running in partial screen views may have undefined behavior.
- Using Flutter in background mode is still a WIP.
- Packing a Flutter library into another sharable library or packing multiple Flutter libraries into an application isn’t supported.

Your **1st** question is answered by the 3rd limitation. If you were considering splitting your simple components up into a separate Flutter library each, then no. You would need to package all your components into a single Flutter library, then let the native app pick from the pool.

For your **2nd** question, can you be more specific what you mean by "*without native hacking*" ? Is there a reason you don't/can't use FlutterViewController?

**3rd** question about passing data between native and Flutter will involve https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

1. From Flutter to native, here's an Android example https://stackoverflow.com/a/49308193/6668797, passing the value "text":

   ```
   // flutter side, send the data
   final String result = await platform.invokeMethod('getBatteryLevel', {"text":text});

   // native side, retrieve it
   String text = call.argument("text");
   ```
2. From native to Flutter, you use `result.success(batteryLevel);` to send it back to `final String result`.