# how do I pass data from native app to flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I have read this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps.

My problem is to pass data from existing native android app to flutter module (such as: token, username...etc). So, I want to ask if there is any way to pass data between Native code in existing native app and code in flutter module?

For example, there are two pages, A and B, A is written in Java code, B embed flutter view, I didn't find any way to pass data from A to the flutter view in B.

```
public class TwoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.two_activity);
        
        //this params passed from HomeActivity 
        String params = getIntent().getStringExtra("params");

        FrameLayout rootView = findViewById(R.id.container);

        View flutterView = Flutter.createView(this, getLifecycle(), "service");

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        rootView.addView(flutterView, layoutParams);
    }
}
```

this is `main.dart`

```
void main() => runApp(chooseWidget(window.defaultRouteName));

Widget chooseWidget(String route) {
  switch(route) {
    case 'service':
      return MyFlutterView();
  }
}

class MyFlutterView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  static const platform = const MethodChannel('samples.flutter.dev/start');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[

          Text(
            'this is a flutter page',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14,
              color: Colors.blue
            ),
          ),

          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              platform.invokeMethod('startActivity');
            },
            child: Text('go native page'),
            color: Colors.purple,
            highlightColor: Colors.deepPurple,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

-------------------------->edit in 2019.7.18<-----------------------------

```
Thank you for your help. I found the answer.
1、BasicMessageChannel：use this to pass string or other object.

2、MethodChannel：use this to method invocation

3、EventChannel: use this to event streams
```

Comment: use systemchannels

Comment: Are there any articles that introduce solutions to similar problems?@MuratAslan

Comment: https://proandroiddev.com/communication-between-flutter-and-native-modules-9b52c6a72dd2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49099408/how-to-pass-a-message-from-flutter-to-native

Comment: see `BasicMessageChannel` for example

Comment: this only solves the problem from flutter to native, but not vice versa.

Comment: no, `BasicMessageChannel` can be used both ways

Comment: where is `Flutter.createView` official documentation?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps

Comment: where is `Flutter` class official documentation? or source code?

Comment: you can see this github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps and above pic. Flutter as  a module imported to the native project.

Comment: @David The normal way to do this is to cache the value you want to send to Flutter in the Java fragment or activity. Once the flutter engine is running (gone though Dart `main()` and the method channel is established, make a native call from Dart to Java to collect the cached information. In the Java implementation of the platform channel method, return the value(s) - could be a single value, Map or List.

Comment: @David how did you solve this?

Comment: @nimi0112 as I mentioned above, use MethodChannel or BasicMessageChannel.

Comment: @David if possible, can you share example through which you have resolved.

Answer (score 2):

You can use method channel for this

```
private static final String CHANNEL = "AndySample/test";

FlutterEngine flutterEngine=new FlutterEngine(this);
flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().executeDartEntrypoint(
    DartExecutor.DartEntrypoint.createDefault()
);
FlutterEngineCache
    .getInstance()
    .put("my_engine_id", flutterEngine);
flutterEngine.getNavigationChannel().setInitialRoute("/");

    
    MethodChannel mc=new 
    MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(),CHANNEL);
    mc.setMethodCallHandler((methodCall, result) ->
        {
            if(methodCall.method.equals("test"))
            {
                result.success("Hai from android and this is the data yopu sent me "+ methodCall.argument("data"));
//Accessing data sent from flutter
            }
            else
            {
                Log.i("new method came",methodCall.method);
            }

        }
    );
```

use this blog to know more

https://medium.com/@andymobitec/flutter-sending-data-between-android-and-flutter-1e0693fbae64

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you the same Andy that wrote the Medium article you're linking to? If so, please be sure to, at minimum, disclose your affiliation to ensure that you don't run afoul of [Stack Overflow's self-promotion and spam rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data with method channel, Yes I am late for answer but it might be useful for other devs.

In native you need to invoke method channel, below is example of android.

```
val testChannel = MethodChannel(flutterEngine!!.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, "method_channel_name")
            testChannel.invokeMethod("method_name", referrerUrl);
```

In Flutter you can listen this invoked method.

```
static const platform = const MethodChannel('method_channel_name');
platform.setMethodCallHandler((call)async{
      // you can get hear method and passed arguments with method 
      print("init state setMethodCallHandler ${call.arguments}");
    });
```