# How can I call headless Dart code in a Flutter app from native platform

Tags: flutter, dart, native, platform

I'm using [quick_actions](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/quick_actions) plugin in one of my Flutter apps and wish to invoke a headless Dart function when user clicks on a shortcut.

I just wish to execute the dart code in background without showing the app screen to the user. I know many plugins like background_fetch, WorkManager etc can schedule to run dart code in background.

I'm assuming that the java code in quick_actions plugin might have to be modified to achieve?

Comment: Seems like you need a service in fllutter to run your dart in the background and then platform-channel to call that code from your android code. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49099408/how-to-pass-a-message-from-flutter-to-native