# How to pass a message from Native Android back to Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I know that we can pass data from `Flutter` to `Native Android`, like @UpaJah mentioned in one of his answers:

[How to pass a message from Flutter to Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49099408/how-to-pass-a-message-from-flutter-to-native)

But i want to get a response from `native android` so that i can update my UI accordingly in `Flutter`. I just have to get response from `native` by any means. How can i do that?

**Update:**

I tried this piece of code as @liu-silong had mentioned in the answer:

```js
bleChannel.invokeMethod("updateUI", 1, new MethodChannel.Result() {
  @Override
  public void success(@Nullable Object result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "success");
  }

  @Override
  public void error(String errorCode, @Nullable String errorMessage, @Nullable Object errorDetails) {
    Log.d(TAG, "errorCode: " + errorCode);
  }

  @Override
  public void notImplemented() {
    Log.d(TAG, "notImplemented");
  }
});
```

Now my code gets inside `notImplemented` callback. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You can call Dart methods through MethodChannel on the Android side

Android:

```java
private MethodChannel channel;
channel = new MethodChannel(getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor(), "channel_name");
// invoke dart method (in the main thread)
channel.invokeMethod("foo", new HashMap<String, Object>());
```

Dart

```dart
final MethodChannel channel = new MethodChannel("channel_name");
channel.setMethodCallHandler(_methodCallHandler);

Future<dynamic> _methodCallHandler(MethodCall call) {
  if(call.method == 'foo'){
   // do sth...
  }
}
```

Or you can also use EventChannel.

https://github.com/liusilong/stack_q

[image]

Comment: I tried using this code but my code never gets inside `_methodCallHandler`

Comment: I tried your code and i have also implemented callbacks and now my code gets inside ' notImplemented' callback.

Comment: @SagarBalyan Try this https://github.com/liusilong/stack_q

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'model.dart';


    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: "Flutter DEMO",
          theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch:Colors.blue ),
          home: MyHomePage(),
        );
        throw UnimplementedError();
      }
    
    }
    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget{
      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        return MyHomePageState();
      }
    
    }
    class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>{
    
      var channel=MethodChannel("baabadevs");
      ConfigElement configElement= ConfigElement(bankPsp: "kjhkh", bankCode: "hgj", publickKey: "hjhggh", maxLimit: 20, bankName: "jhghjgjh", clMobileNumber: "jhghjgjhgjg", k0Hex: "gjgjhgjhg", payValidInSec: "68767", collectValidInSec: "6876786", maxDebitAmount: 8687678, orgRefUrl: "hghjgjg", maxVpa: 3 );
      //ConfigElement _configElement=ConfigElement(bankPsp: "kjhkh", bankCode: "hgj", publickKey: "hjhggh", maxLimit: 20, bankName: "jhghjgjh", clMobileNumber: "jhghjgjhgjg", k0Hex: "gjgjhgjhg", clTokenExpDays: 30, payValidInSec: 68767, collectValidInSec: 6876786, maxDebitAmount: 8687678, orgRefUrl: "hghjgjg", maxVpa: 3, );
      var list=List<String>;
       String _sensorAvailable="Unknown";
        getConfigElement(ConfigElement configElement){
          setState(() {
            this.configElement=configElement as ConfigElement;
    
            /*configElement.bankCode=list[0];
            configElement.bankName=list[1];
            configElement.bankPsp=list[2];
            configElement.k0Hex=list[3];
            configElement.maxVpa=list[4];
            configElement.clMobileNumber=list[5];
            configElement.collectValidInSec=list[6];
            configElement.orgRefUrl=list[7];
            configElement.payValidInSec=list[8];
            configElement.publickKey=list[9];
            configElement.maxDebitAmount=list[10];
            configElement.maxLimit=list[11];*/
          });
        }
      showToast() async{
          ConfigElement configElement= ConfigElement.fromJson(await channel.invokeMethod("showToast",{'message':"Subscribe to this channel"}))  ;
          getConfigElement(configElement);
    
    
      }
    
    
      /*Future<void> _checkAvailability() async{
        try{
         var available= await methodChannel.invokeMethod('isSensorAvailable');
         setState(() {
           _sensorAvailable= available.toString();
         });
        }catch(E){
          print(E);
        }
      }*/
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
        return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
                    showToast();
                  }, child: Text("show toast")),
                  Text("Bank Code: ${configElement.bankCode}",maxLines:1,style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                  //Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
                  Text('Bank Name: ${configElement.bankName}',maxLines:1,style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                  //Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
                  Text('Bank Psp: ${configElement.bankPsp}',maxLines:1,style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                  //Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
                  Text('clMobileNumber:${configElement.clMobileNumber}',maxLines:1,style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                  //Text("clToken Expiry days: ${configElement.clTokenExpDays}",maxLines:1,style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                  //Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
                  Text('Collect valid in sec: ${configElement.collectValidInSec}',maxLines:1,style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                  //Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
                  Text('K0Hex value: ${configElement.k0Hex}',maxLines:1,style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                  //Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
                  Text('max Debit Amount:${configElement.maxDebitAmount}',maxLines:1,style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                  Text("max Limit: ${configElement.maxLimit}",maxLines:1,style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                  //Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
                  Text('max VPA: ${configElement.maxVpa}',maxLines:1,style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                  //Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
                  Text('ORG REF URL: ${configElement.orgRefUrl}',maxLines:1,style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                  //Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
                  Text('pay Valid In sec:${configElement.payValidInSec}',maxLines:1,style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                  Text('Collect Valid In sec:${configElement.collectValidInSec}',maxLines:1,style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                  Text('max Debit Amount:${configElement.maxDebitAmount}',maxLines:1,style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                  Text('orgRefURL:${configElement.orgRefUrl}',maxLines:1,style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                  Text('maxVpa:${configElement.maxVpa}',maxLines:1,style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
    
                ],
              ),
            )
        );
      }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here You will get the respective android native code structure to pass the response to flutter back.
[imageLink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E79cW.png)

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.