# How we can interact with Android through dart? Is there any packages in Dart? For Eg. Python has a package related to OS

Tags: android, flutter, dart

In python
`import os` command is used to interact with the OS. I just want to know, Is there any **Dart Packages** similiar to python's package? Because, we are currently working with an **android app** which need to be interact with the OS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a message from Flutter to Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49099408/how-to-pass-a-message-from-flutter-to-native)

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to do? Interacting with the OS can mean a lot of different things when it comes to Android and there's no one single package for those - accessing OS's bluetooth status, internet status, opening camera, gallery, checking battery level etc.

Comment: Basically we are building an android app which maintains the screen time of other android apps like Digital Wellbeing. For that purpose we need some sort of services from the android OS. So, Is there any dart/flutter packages related to my need?

Comment: I found some packages like app_usage, device_apps  these are some what good. But the documentation of these packages are really less..